# Map values from one array to another using indices

Tags: python, numpy

I have two 1-dimensional numpy arrays, let's call them `arr1` and `arr2`. They have a length of `M` and `N` respectively, and we know that `M < N`. I know that each index of the first array maps to multiple indices of the second array. Currently, I have this mapping in a dictionary, where the keys are the indices of `arr1` and the values are the indices of `arr2`. The mapping dictionary could look something like this:

```py
m = {
    #idx of arr1: list of idxs of arr2
    0: [0,1],
    1: [1,2],
    2: [3,4],
}
```

If I want to perform an operation (let's say summation in this example) and `arr2 = array([1,5,7,9,12])` I would expect `arr1` to be:

```py
arr1 = np.array([6, 12, 21])
```

For the first element, we sum elements 0 and 1 to get 6 (1+5), for the second, we get 12 (5+7), and for the third, we get 21 (9+12).

One way to achieve what I want is with a for loop like the following:

```py
for key, val in m.items():
    arr1[key] = arr2[val].sum()
```

Now, this works and is pretty simple, however, it involves a for loop which I'm looking to avoid, since the size of the arrays is in the 100,000s in my program. If anyone has a quicker solution I'd love to know!

NOTE (EDIT): The length of the values of the dictionary is not guaranteed to be the same, but the keys are guaranteed to be in order and all present (i.e. range(M))

Comment: well, you can parallelize the operations, since they are independent of each other. This looks like a good task you can delegate to a GPU

Comment: yes, but the CPU time would be the same (probably higher), so if there's a faster way using numpy slices or something it would be even better. I'll look into delegating to GPU tho, thanks!

Comment: How is the CPU time higher? Using a GPU to do the operations the CPU will only need to assemble the results of the GPU into one array of size M. Without using a GPU the CPU will have to generate M results each having an average of N/M sums.

Comment: Sorry, I was referring to higher CPU time assuming the CPU was doing the parallelization, for some reason the entire question hadn't loaded. You are correct

Answer (score 0):

If the keys of the dictionary happens to be `range(len(m))`:

```
>>> arr2[list(m.values())].sum(-1)
array([ 6, 12, 21])
```

If the value or order cannot be guaranteed:

```
>>> m
{1: [1, 2], 2: [3, 4], 0: [0, 1]}
>>> arr1 = np.zeros(max(m) + 1)
>>> arr1[list(m)] = arr2[list(m.values())].sum(-1)
>>> arr1
array([ 6., 12., 21.])
```

There is a limitation: each value in your dictionary must be the same length.

Comment: Ah yes, I meant to say that the values can have any length (even 0), but thanks!